# How to expire page cache with Capybara and Selenium

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

How can you tell Capybara to expire/clear a page that has been cached?

Capybara is using a page cached from one test on an entirely different test:

```
class MySystemTest < ApplicationSystemTestCase

  test 'get cached page' do
    ...
    visit my_url
    ...
  end

  test 'get cached page again' do
    ...
    visit my_url
    ...
  end

end
```

I've tried adding `clear_local_storage: true` and `clear_session_storage: true` to the `Capybara::Selenium::Driver` initialization, but that didn't change anything.

My environment:

`Rails 6.0.2`, `selenium-webdriver (3.142.6)`, `ChromeDriver (86.0.4240.22)`

Comment: Was also looking for a solution for this, but it doesn't look like it's possible. My workaround was to use the `rack_test` driver for some tests (because for instance you can check response_headers and read the cache-control settings for your responses), and for some of the chrome ones, I just added a trivial parameter to the end of the url I was visiting (eg. `?x=0` - and you can change it in each test) - not the best but seemed to work pretty well